# Is there any way we can store depth/level in a hashmap of level and arraylist of node iterative depth first search?

Tags: java, stack, iteration, depth-first-search

I know it is some kind of coding challenge, I was trying to solve a problem I solved it using BFS but I want to solve it using dfs too. So is there a way we can store depth with node in Iterative DFS, I know this can be easily achieved using recursion. Here is my progress:

```
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<TreeNode>> getUsingDFS(TreeNode root){
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<TreeNode>> map = new HashMap();
    
        List<TreeNode> visited = new ArrayList();
        
        Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack();
        stack.add(root);
        int level = 0;
        
        int top = 1;
        
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            TreeNode tempNode = stack.pop();

            //level / depth store here.
            map.put(level, map.getOrDefault(level, new ArrayList()).add(tempNode));
            
            
            visited.add(tempNode);
            
            if(tempNode.left != null){
                queue.add(tempNode.left);
            }
            
             if(tempNode.right != null){
                queue.add(tempNode.right);
            }
                
            

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"store depth"*? Store where, for what purpose?

Comment: Are you asking how to do an iterative depth first search? If so, did you try searching for solutions, e.g. with web search for [`iterative depth first search`](https://www.google.com/search?q=iterative+depth+first+search)?

Comment: So i want to store depth as key and arraylist of node in a hashmap. I have edited the question.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, there is a way. Now read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: So you mean you want to store the depth of the `TreeNode` object in the queue together with the object? If so create a class with those two values as fields. and add that to the queue instead.

Comment: Andreas in dfs how will you keep track of depth, as you do not know level from stack. If you create an object to store level with treenode still you have to track level of each node while popping and pushing the element in stack.

Comment: That's what the class is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I achieved this.

```
 public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<LevelNode>> getUsingDFS(TreeNode root){
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<LevelNode>> map = new HashMap();
        
        Queue<LevelNode> queue = new LinkedList();
        queue.add(new LevelNode(root, 0));
        
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            LevelNode tempNode = queue.poll();
            
            ArrayList<LevelNode> list = map.getOrDefault(tempNode.level, new ArrayList());
            list.add(tempNode);
            
            map.put(tempNode.level, list);
            
            if(tempNode.node.left != null){
                queue.add(new LevelNode(tempNode.node.left, tempNode.level+1));
            }
            
             if(tempNode.node.right != null){
                queue.add(new LevelNode(tempNode.node.right, tempNode.level+1));
            }
        }
        return map;
 }

class LevelNode{
    TreeNode node;
    int level;
    
    LevelNode(TreeNode node, int level){
        this.level = level;
        this.node = node;
    }
}
```